# why I get Connection closed by remote host when trying to git push

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I am trying to push my work to github and I get the following error

```
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by xxx.xx.xx.xxx port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I used ssh to clone the repo so I have already created a key.
Any ideas?

Comment: Confirm the ssh key still works? https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection

Comment: See if port 22 is not blocked

Comment: @evolutionxbox when passing $ ssh -T git@github.com I get "ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known" why is that?

Comment: Is the remote repo on github ? Are you behind a proxy? Can you access the remote's host through a browser?

Comment: yes the remote repo is on github and yes i am behind a proxy. I didn't understand what do mean by your last question

Comment: Try pasting the address at the browser.

Comment: @JimmyKane when running ```netstat -aon``` I don't see it. Maybe it is blocked but How can open it?

Comment: i figured out what was the problem. It was a routing problem. I had to check the DNS config

Answer (score 1):

As illustrated by [this ticket](https://clientarea.emwd.com/knowledgebase/94/Unable-to-SSH----Connection-closed-by-remote-host.html)

> The most typical reason for the Connection closed by remote host error message is your connection is being denied by our host access system.
>
> We maintain an host access list for allowed IPs to our server.
> Only IP addresses listed in the host access list is allowed to connect to the server via SSH. This approach dramatically increases the security of the server and reduces its resource load as our firewall does not have to deal with hundreds of brute force attempts per minute.

So if you have access to the remote server, checking its DNS configuration is indeed the right approach. Also the remote [`sshd_config`](https://serverfault.com/a/1004113/783).